# How to define a probability measure in both discrete and continuous cases?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space.

My main doubt relies on how to properly define the measure $P$.

If $X$ is a random variable, the induce probability space may be defined as $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mu)$, isn't it? Where $\mathcal{B}(R)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

In this induced probability space, how can I define $\mu$?

Here is what I thought:

If $X$ is a discrete random variable, then $\mu(B)$, with $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, equals to $\sum_k P(X = k) = \sum_k p(k)$, right? Is this a kind of "Lebesgue Measure over an interval of $\mathbb{R}$"? I am trying to visualize it as being the length of the desired interval in $\mathbb{R}$ weighted by $p(k)$'s. Does it make any sense?

How could this be extended to some continuous random variable $X$?

Comment: It appears, from the way you formulate your question, that you think that these are the only two cases! There are also non-discrete [singular measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_measure). Monotone right-continuous functions with lower limit 0 and upper limit 1 give us (all) cumulative distribution functions and probability measures are their "derivatives" (for example, see [Chung's book](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9780121741518)).

Comment: You have a good answer to your question below; you should consider accepting it (click on the checkmark on the left of the answer) if you’ve found it helpful.

Comment: Hey, @Theoretical Economist, sure! I did not know that I was supposed to do that, thank you for the advice! ;) Done

Comment: @André no worries! Now you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Borel sets $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, $\mu(B)$ is defined to be $P(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in B\})$, i.e., $P(X^{-1}[B])$. It makes no difference in this definition whether $X$ is discrete or continuous.